# Weird graphic glitch when using fullscreen on intel graphics since last ubuntu update

Tags: drivers, graphics, lenovo, intel-graphics, fullscreen

**my system:**
Lenovo Thinkbook 15 Gen4 (IAP)
12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1255U × 12
Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

**My Problem:**
After the last software updates a few weeks ago, i now have a weird graphics glitch wich renders my device partially unusable.
The bug only appears when i switch something to fullscreen. Be it videos in the browser, pictures with image viewer, videos with VLC, or any other window wich allows being set to fullscreen via the F11 key.
Also maybe worth to note: windows runs fine on this machine. So no hw/firmware issue.

I would be super thankful if someone of you good people over here could guide me on how to solve this problem.   
Attached below are example pictures of a fullscreen YT-video with and without the glitch and also a screenshot of the "additional drivers" window.   


This might also help?

```
user@device:~$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 0c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:169 memory:601c000000-601cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

```
user@device:~$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:46a8] (rev 0c)
```

```
user@device:~$ lspci -nnk | egrep -i --color 'vga|3d|2d' -A3 | grep 'in use'
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
```

[PICTURE: fullscreen without glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r3SR.jpg)

[PICTURE: fullscreen with glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxLmJ.jpg)

[SCREENSHOT: "additional drivers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zCXg.png)

Thank you very much for your help!! :)